# Configure spring.* boot properties from cloud config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

This seems like a really basic question but I can't find a straight answer anywhere.

How do I configure basic Spring Boot properties from a Cloud Config Server instance?   Obviously the properties for Spring boot which pertain to the config server (i.e. cloud.config.uri, *.username, *.password) must be in bootstrap.yml

What about the other properties available here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties

I'd like spring.rabbitmq.addresses and the like to come from my config server instance and not to be hardcoded into a bootstrap or application yml.

If I throw that particular property up into my Git Repo, the Spring AMQP just still defaults to localhost.   It looks to me like the setting in Git is completely ignored.

Comment: You mentioned `bootstrap.yml` set the `cloud.config.uri` property. The properties in `bootstrap.yml` needed to access the Cloud Config server are actually `spring.application.name`, `spring.cloud.config.uri` and  `spring.cloud.config.label`.

Comment: yeah I was being brief.   My connectivity to my cloud config server functions correctly.   My whole app currently works correctly  with @Values getting wired in with the settings from the config server.

Answer (score 0):

So investigation into the code reveals my question was based on some false assumptions.   It doesn't look like there is any underlying unity whatsoever to the spring.* properties for Spring Boot.

For instance the Spring Rabbit properties I was referring to come from a Rabbit specific object: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitProperties

This gets pulled in by RabbitAutoConfiguration.java.   RabbitProperties certainly doesn't have anything in it that would be capable of referencing a Spring Cloud Config Server value.   I still need to track down where RabbitProperties gets made as a bean.

For the time being, I hacked my own implementation of a RabbitProperties bean and marked it @Primary.   I just used the standard @Value to pull in my desiired values from the Cloud Config Server.   This will get me by for a POC I am doing, but is a hack since the RabbitProperties has a ton of possible configurations.  I certainly don't want to duplicate everything in there.

```
 @EnableRabbit
 @Configuration
 public class RabbitConfigurer {

     @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host:'localhost'}")
     private String host;

     @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port:5672}")
     private int port;

     @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
     private String username;

     @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
     private String password;

     @Bean
     @Primary
     public RabbitProperties rabbitProperties() {

        RabbitProperties rabbitProperties = new RabbitProperties();
        rabbitProperties.setHost(host);
        rabbitProperties.setPort(port);
        rabbitProperties.setUsername(username);
        rabbitProperties.setPassword(password);

        return rabbitProperties;
     }
 }
```